# Find exponential of a complex number

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I want to calculate the exponential of a complex number such as `2+3i`.

I already know this formula

> exp( *i* z ) = cos(z) + *i* sin(z)

Is there a built-in function in OpenCV? If yes, could you please explain it to me with an example?

Comment: Please forgive if this is very simple question as I am new to this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What’s wrong with the `cexp( )` function declared in `complex.h`?  Why do you want to use OpenCV instead of the standard library?

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double complex z = 2 + 3*I;
    double complex w = cexp(z);
    printf("%f + %fi\n", creal(w), cimag(w));
    return 0;
}
```

If you’re targeting a platform that doesn’t provide complex types or operations, you can use the following for a quick-and-dirty solution:

```
struct mycomplex { double real; double imag; }

struct mycomplex my_exp(struct mycomplex z) {
    struct mycomplex w;
    w.real = exp(z.real)*cos(z.imag);
    w.imag = exp(z.real)*sin(z.imag);
    return w;
}
```

And finally, since you’re using MSVC, a very rudimentary C++ example:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto z = std::complex<double>(2,3);
    auto w = std::exp(z);
    std::cout << w << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I got it but there is a problem. When i write    double complex z = 2 + 3*I;         It says Error: Expected a ;

Comment: What compiler are you using, and did you `#include <complex.h>`?

Comment: Yes I have included complex.h .I am working on Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 ultimate on x64 platform.

Comment: So, MSVC isn’t actually a C compiler in any meaningful sense; it supports only a rather limited historical form of the C language.  If you’re going to use it, you’ll be much better off writing C++.  If you want to stick with both MSVC and C, you can use the workaround in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Please tell me the solution in C++.

Comment: @Navdeep: I provided a basic C++ example as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you're looking for is `atan2`. For example, for the number `2+3i`, you would compute the angle as

```
T = atan2( 3.0, 2.0 );
```

Comment: Actually I am asking about Euler's number. I want the answer in terms of cos and sins as I am working on DFT

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is any inbuild function in c to solve this. in fact when we were doing FFT transform in c, we used the basic cos + jsin version

Comment: I also tried to use it but the c program is considering j to be some variable and it is displaying the error "j undefined". How can I resolve it. Actually I am also working on DFT. Thanks

Comment: you can try something like this.
calculate the value of e^j and use that in your code, as this value will not change. then you can easily multiple sin(value) with it.